# Order tags by recent usage count rather than usage for all time

Tags: feature-request

I am using Visual Studio 2017. When I go to add the tag for that by typing in `visualst`, it brings up a bunch of Visual Studio tags sorted descending by count. Because VS 2017 is relatively new compared to the others, its tag hasn't gotten as much use as the older versions, so you have to basically type out the entire tag to get it to show.

Instead of sorting tags descending by count for all time, tags could be sorted first by a count within a windowed time frame (within past 90 days, for example) and sorted second for all time.

This would allow tags that are used at a higher frequency within a more recent time frame to gain priority.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any evidence that such a sorting would have produced a different outcome? If any one of the other tags have more recent history than the one you're looking for, they will still show up first in the list. If they are all somewhat similar then it would be basically random sorting.

Comment: Can't we just get rid of all those version tags in the first place. Problem solved!

Comment: Unless we add a "last asked" date to those tag info boxes, people are just going to get confused. It's already not obvious that they are sorted by the gray numbers to the right of tags. Sorting by something that's not visible would be even worse.

Comment: @TinyGiant Evidence is anecdotal as I've sorted database records before based on their usage within a time frame. And you're correct, if 2010 is used more than 2017 in the past 90-120 days, it would be ranked higher, but that should be the expected outcome. With the current sorting, if Stack Exchange were 20 years old, Windows 98 would rank higher than Windows 7, 8, and 10.

Comment: @HereticMonkey All questions already have a creation timestamp. An entry-level developer could easily write a query to aggregate that value at the tag level. It would be transparent anyway. As for confusion, it's already confusing that not only is VS 2017 not initially visible in the list, but is eclipsed in priority by VS 2010 which was released over eight years ago.

Comment: Saying that an entry-level developer could write a query to do something says nothing about the performance implications of the query they write. Remember, this site gets huge amounts of traffic and has a decent amount of data. "It would be transparent anyway". I'm not sure how sorting by a piece of information I have no visibility to is in any way transparent.

Comment: @HereticMonkey A daily or even weekly task could do the aggregation. It doesn't need to be calculated in real time. It's transparent in that you only see the end result of the ranking rather than all of the metadata used to calculate it.